# Sanitize with truncate messing up overflow: hidden

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have some html that should look like this:

[image]

```
 <% @post.limit(2).each do |post| %>

 <div style="float: left;">
 <%= image_tag post.avatar %>
 </div>

 <div style="overflow: hidden;">
 <%= sanitize(post.body[0.100]) %>
 </div>

 <% end %>
```

The problem is the second loops content collapses inside the firsts overflow, making it look like there's a missing `</div>` tag, like this:

[image]

After a long time clearing up the html to find the missing div tag (I thought was the problem) I realized what was causing the problem was this line:

```
<%= sanitize(post.body[0..100]) %>
```

If I just put:

```
<%= sanitize post.body %>
```

or

```
<%= post.body[0..100] %>
```

it works. But sanitize with truncate messes it up.

Comment: Its because HTML tags are likely getting cut off because of the truncate.  Try truncating the string after sanitizing it.

Comment: Ahh that makes sense, although i'm unsure of what the syntax would look like to do that.

Comment: `sanitize(post.body)[0..100]`

Comment: That fixes the div issue except now the html is showing up. Does that mean sanitize is not working?

Comment: Ok, nice i got it with <%= sanitize(post.body, tags: %w(p img)).truncate(200, :separator => " ").html_safe %> . If you'd like to add your comment as an answer i'll accept it. thanks for the help :)